# Implement webview in background after user is logged in

Tags: android, multithreading, webview, android-studio, background-process

I am developing a hybrid android application which uses native as well as webview to do certain things. I want that once user logs in webview in a certain site like Facebook then he should remain logged in. He should not be logged out from that particular site. How can I implement this?

I have tried to use setSavePassword but it says it is deprecated after API level 18. Should I run a background thread in a new webview which runs always with the context of main webview or should I implement this using service (I think that consumes lot of RAM)?

Comment: what do you mean `should not be logged out`, how long are we talking? If you quit the application and force stop it, should it still remember the login? Or only along different views of your application?

Comment: It should remain log in till the time we either don't log out particularly or we don't clear the data by going into setting (or anyother application that clears data).

Comment: That actually depends on the site. You might need to save a token that identifies you (as it is with the `Accounts`), or do some other app-specific magic to remember that you are you, maybe with cookies or other data.